# Run same test on multiple datasets

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, pytest

I'm starting to use pytest to add unit test to a software that can analyse different kind of datasets.

I wrote a set of test functions that I would like to apply to different datasets. One complication is that the datasets are quite big, so I would like to do:

- Load dataset1
- Run tests
- Load dataset2
- Run tests

and so on.

Right now I'm able to use one dataset using a fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def data():
    return load_dataset1()
```

and then passing `data`to each test function.

I know that I can pass the `params` keyword to `pytest.fixture`. But, how can I implement the sequential load of the different datasets (not loading all of them in RAM at the same time)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `params` as you mentioned:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module', params=[load_dataset1, load_dataset2])
def data(request):
    loader = request.param
    dataset = loader()
    return dataset
```

Use [`fixture finalization`](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code) if you want to do fixture specific finalization:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module', params=[load_dataset1, load_dataset2])
def data(request):
    loader = request.param
    dataset = loader()
    def fin():
        # finalize dataset-related resource
        pass
    request.addfinalizer(fin)
    return dataset
```

Answer (score 1):

Falsetru's answer is quite good, but because this is a hard problem, I wanted to share a slightly different solution using `@pytest.mark.parametrize`.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def data1():
    return get_dataset1()

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def data2():
    return get_dataset2()

@pytest.mark.parametrize('data_fixture',
                         ['data1','data2'])
def test_datafoo_is_bar(data_fixture, request):
   data = request.getfixturevalue(data_fixture)
   assert data[foo] == bar
```

Comment: `assert data[foo] == bar`

Comment: Why don't you pass the fixtures themselves instead of strings: `[data1, data2]`

Comment: @falsetru - That was my first try, but it unfortunately doesn't give the right behavior - you get a reference to the fixture function when what you really want is its result. Even worse, it no longer behaves like a fixture, and it will break things like chained fixtures, parameterized fixtures, and fixtures with module scope.